# I want the elements which are in sequence (1,2,3) (6,7) (10,11) (15,16,17). separately

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am having following array:`arrtooth`

```
var arrtooth = tooth.split('|');
```

It gets value

```
arrtooth=[1,2,3,6,7,10,11,15,16,17];
```

I want the elements which are in sequence `(1,2,3) (6,7) (10,11) (15,16,17)`.
separately.My code is in Jquery.I just want the actual logic.

If i get the output as 3 2 2 3 in an array it will be fine or if you have any thing (output) which can elaborate the sequence will be ok.

Comment: Whats the sequence 3 2 2 3. How are you separating the array. Above all what have you tried so far?

Comment: What form do you want the output in? An array of arrays containing the consecutive subsets? A string?

Comment: @Subir Kumar Saoyes you are right I want 3 2 2 3 .It will be also fine.

Comment: What have you tried? you are not stating that you ran into a problem, but rather "Here is a problem solve it for me"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arrtooth = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17];
var last = arrtooth[0];
var result = [];
count = 1;
for (var i = 1; i < arrtooth.length; i++) {
    if (arrtooth[i] == (last + 1)) {
        count++;

    } else {
        result.push(count);
        count = 1;
    }
    last = arrtooth[i];
}
result.push(count);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xjVPq/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrtooth=[1,2,3,6,7,10,11,15,16,17];

var a = arrtooth.reduce(function(result, cur,index, array){
     if( index == 0 || array[index-1] + 1 !== cur ){
        result.push(0);
     }
     result[ result.length-1 ]++;
     return result;
},[]);

console.log(a);   //[3,2,2,3];
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6QG6f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the array contains integers that are otherwise ordered, the following two functions will provide you with the consecutive subsets that you're after. The first produces a string output, the second produces a two-dimensional array.

```
var arrtooth = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17];

function stringOutput(arrtooth) {
    var outputString = '(';
    for (var i = 0; i < arrtooth.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) outputString += arrtooth[i];
        else if (arrtooth[i] - 1 == arrtooth[i - 1]) outputString += ',' + arrtooth[i];
        else outputString += ') (' + arrtooth[i];
    }
    outputString += ')';
    return outputString;
}

function arrayOutput(arrtooth) {
    var outputArray = [],
        toothArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrtooth.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0 || arrtooth[i] - 1 != arrtooth[i - 1]) {
            toothArray = [];
            outputArray.push(toothArray);
        }
        toothArray.push(arrtooth[i]);
    }
    return outputArray;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DSUeZ/)